# Wordpress Contact Form 7 add more button to add fields row dynamically

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts, contact-form-7

I am working on WordPress projects and I wanted to develop a functionality like once the user clicks on adding more button at that time 4 fields will be added on the form, If press gain to add more button same functionality perform. make sure on email templates this need to be updated accordingly.

can anyone help me to solve the problem? I Googled but can't find anything related to this issue.

Note: I am using Wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin and this functionality will work on also the front side.

Comment: You could look for more complete form plugins like gravity forms or ninja forms which have more advanced features. Getting this to work in contact-form-7 will be hard. You might as well create it all yourself.

Comment: Are you looking for conditional fields , I have used this free add-on for CF7 which have done the exact thing, i.e. show some fields only when some other field has some option chosen etc... https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/ see if it works for your needs?

Comment: Does anyone have this solution ??